# Git pull all commits referring to a single file in remote repo unrelated to my local repo

Tags: git, file, pull, any, remote-repository

I would like to `pull` [this file](https://github.com/florinpop17/app-ideas/commits/master/Projects/Simple-Online-Store.md) (there are 3 commits so far) via Git into my own local repository, which isn't related to that GitHub repo at all. Is it possible to somehow `pull` all commits related to this specific file?

In other words is it possible to download **any file** (meaning commits related to it) located in **any arbitrary repository** - which is not added as a remote in my repo nor cloned - I have access to?

If I understand Git correctly - I can `pull` changes from remote branch to local branch by first `fetch`'ing them, but my repo has to have added repo of such branch as a remote. If so, is it just as simple as adding new remote repo and just `pull`ing specific branch (or even `cherry-pick` only desired commits), and that should just create new branch in my local repo with all or chosen (`cherry-pick`ed) commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best bet is to checkout the individual file and commit each rev.

```
git remote add new_repo PATH_TO_REPO.git
git fetch new_repo
git checkout <SHA> -- my_file.txt
git add my_file.txt
```

Repeat for each commit

Comment: He'll need to `git fetch` after adding the remote (or use the `-f` option to do it automatically).

Comment: I didn't have to repeat `git add` for every commit, because once file was created in my repo, subsequent `git checkout`'s had been modifying already existing file, so I just had to commit new versions to my repo.

Answer (score 2):

`git pull` doesn't really operate on *files*, but rather on *commits*.  All `git pull` does is run `git fetch`, then run `git merge` or some other second Git command you choose.  The `fetch` step obtains commits, and the `merge` step—which you probably *don't* want—merges those commits with your current (`HEAD`) commit-and-branch.

You definitely have the right idea in the parenthetical parts here:

> In other words is it possible to download ... (... commits related to some specific file) ...

The tricks are:

1. finding those commits (you've used GitHub to achieve this);
2. but then actually using them once you've found and obtained them.

You can only either get the whole commit, or nothing; and if you get a whole commit, you also get all of the commits that *lead up to* that one commit.  The [app-ideas repository](https://github.com/florinpop17/app-ideas) (in which the file you want appears) contains, at the moment I write this and and using the information from GitHub only without actually looking any closer, 332 commits.  It also shows five branch names.

You *can* add all 332 commits to your repository, or in some cases (but not this one) some subset of all 332, without using the name of a remote:

```
git fetch https://github.com/florinpop17/app-ideas <refspec> [<refspec> ...]
```

will bring in the commits identified by the *`refspec`* argument(s), and remember what it brought in via both `FETCH_HEAD` and the *`refspec`* argument.  But:

```
git remote add app-ideas https://github.com/florinpop17/app-ideas
git fetch app-ideas
```

is *more convenient* because it does the same, then adds five *remote-tracking* names corresponding to the five branch names.  You would now have a *name* `app-ideas/master`, for instance.  It does require a bit more typing up front, but it saves you work later, and eventually you simply run `git remote remove app-ideas` when you are done with it.

To do this without a remote, you'd have to, for instance:

```
git fetch https://github.com/florinpop17/app-ideas master:tempbranch
```

to create your own branch named `tempbranch`, instead of using `app-ideas/master`.  You could even create *no* branch and just rely on `FETCH_HEAD`, but then you have to remember that the *next* `git fetch` you run—or have `git pull` run—will wipe it out and some or all of those 332 commits may disappear from your own repository.  You'll still eventually want to delete `tempbranch`, probably, so you haven't really saved much if anything.

In any case, after fetching, you have all 322 commits in your repository.  These commits relate to each other, but not to any of the *other* commits in your repository.  In graph theory terms, their commits, as named and found by your `app-ideas/master` or `tempbranch`, form a *disjoint subgraph* from all of your own commits, named and found by your own branch names.

At this point, you can use Git's various other operations, including `git cherry-pick` or (as in [EncryptedWatermelon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57401508/1256452)) `git checkout`, to work with stuff from their commits, and add it to your (still independent) commits.  When you're done, delete either the remote name, or the `tempbranch` name, whichever method you used.  Their commits will become unfind-able and will eventually fall back out of your repository.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. Yet EncryptedWatermelon's answer was easier to apply.